# FPC no longer hooked up to redis?

Tags: full-page-cache, redis, caching

I recently received the following ticket info regarding some caching issues on our magento installation, and have run into some stumbling blocks in diagnosing (thus obviously fixing, as well) the underlying issue:

> saving changes to any static content in the admin is no longer invalidating that page in the cache. E.g., editing a few words on the 'About Us' page and saving doesn't change anything on the front end, we'd then need to refresh the entire FPC to see our tiny tweak
>
> ...snip...
>
> The way it used to work (a few months back), is that upon saving a change, that page and only that page would update on the front end (taking a little longer to load because the cache for that page was invalidated).
>
> At some point (not sure when), we began needing to flush the entire cache and redis cache for the change to appear, which meant the entire site's cache was cleared and everything loaded slowly (and the db takes a huge womping for a bit).
>
> After a bit of that, we realized we didn't even need to flush the redis cache, as it seemed to make no difference, so we've just been flushing the magento cache after any changes ever since.
>
> ...snip...
>
> essentially upon updating the FPC module a while back, redis seems to have been cut out of the process of flushing the cache, so potentially it's been disconnected and may be the culprit.

In attempting to diagnose this problem, I've verified that everything [on an applicable magento devdoc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/using_redis.html#config-mage) seems to be set up correctly between **FPC** and **redis**, *as far as I can tell*.  IE `app/etc/local.xml` has the correct options for an installation not using *Zend_Cache*.

If anybody has any other ideas, or pointers on documentation that may help further with this issue, I would be very grateful.  I seem to be having a bit of an issue locating decent magento documentation, on some issues, on this project.  Thanks in advance!

---

Addendum:  contents of *local.xml* follow

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 12 Aug 2014 09:19:47 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
          <key>***[redacted]***</key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username>***[redacted]***</username>
                    <password>***[redacted]***</password>
                    <dbname>***[redacted]***</dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>

        <redis_session>
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <port>6379</port>
            <password>***[redacted]***</password>
            <timeout>2.5</timeout>
            <persistent></persistent>
            <db>2</db>
            <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
            <compression_lib>lzf</compression_lib>
            <log_level>1</log_level>
            <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
            <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
            <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
            <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>
            <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>
            <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>
            <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>
            <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>
            <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>
        </redis_session>

      <cache>
        <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
        <backend_options>
          <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
          <port>6379</port>
          <persistent></persistent>
          <database>0</database>
          <password>***[redacted]***</password>
          <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
          <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
          <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
          <compress_data>1</compress_data>
          <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
          <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
          <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
        </backend_options>
      </cache>

      <fpc>
          <lifetime>86400</lifetime>
          <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
              <server>127.0.0.1</server>
              <port>6379</port>
              <persistent>cache-fpc</persistent>
              <database>1</database>
              <password>***[redacted]***</password>
              <force_standalone>1</force_standalone>
              <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
              <lifetimelimit>86400</lifetimelimit>
              <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
              <compress_data>1</compress_data>
              <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
              <compress_data>gzip</compress_data>
          </backend_options>
      </fpc>

    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like cache invalidation isn't happening.  There are some additional notes to consider from Colin about the module `Cm_Redis` used in default installations as well that offer more insight. Particularly the garbage collection nightly.  You may also look over the issues of the module to see if any others have reported similar issues.

- https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis

Also, running multiple Redis instances for sessions/blocks/FPC may also help the pruning processes.

`AOE_TemplateHints` module is good for identifying a state of blocks cache that may help you debug the issue.

- https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints

Comment: Thank you for the information that you've given so far; it's been very valuable.  I was wondering if you might suggest where these notes from Colin about `Cm_Redis` might be found.  I will also continue looking through the other references that you've given.  We're already using multiple Redis instances (three I believe).

Thank you very much for your time & help on this matter, @B00MER.

Comment: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis#related--tuning Is what I was mainly referring to, you may also look into a monitoring plugin like Munin and/or some interface to Redis to get more insight on keys/expiration/etc. What does your `local.xml` current look like? (minus sensitive info obviously)

Comment: I went ahead and edited the original post to included the contents of $INSTALLATION/app/etc/local.xml as per your request.  I believe I've scrubbed it of all sensitive data.  I'm seeing under the <fpc> section that the lifetime is set at 24 hours.  I'm guessing that setting this to a shorter interval might bring about the behavior that we'd like to see; unfortunately I believe this would probably add an unacceptable amount of load avg to the server.  Do you know if redis should automatically detect a static page modification (currently not happening)?

Comment: Also, I wanted to thank you again, and also mention that we'll be looking into _Munin_ and/or other interfaces to _Redis_ to gain a little more insight on the behavior.  Still very grateful for any insight that you might be able to impart on the matter, of course.  :)

Comment: I noticed you are using the same redis instance for each cache, it would be best to create a separate redis server instance for session, block and fpc.  Also, you don't need to compress the FPC as its already compressed.  This doc from Magento ECG may be helpful: http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/MagentoECG-UsingRedisasaCacheBackendinMagento.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the update, B00MER.  I'll be reading up more on that and, as always, appreciate the tips bringing me up to a better speed on this.

Comment: Yet another small update to this issue (though probably very important):  It looks like we're using the **Lesti** extension for _FPC_.  Sorry for the previous ambiguity.  Also, being as this was kind of a conglomeration of issues after the FPC<-->redis issue was solved, I opened a [new thread with this issue trimmed down just to the important components](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71366/why-arent-cached-pages-invalidating-fpc-redis-after-being-modified-on-the-ser).

Comment: Voted to close since moved to a new question.